# VB .Net GDI+ usar Clip solo para una region

Tags: .net

Mi pregunta es respecto a la función SetClip/Clip.
Estoy creando un control que muestra una lista, y la forma de esta lista es rectangular de puntas redondeadas. Con la función DrawPath creo sin problemas el contorno de la figura:

```
G.DrawPath(Pen1, XRoundRectangle(New Rectangle(0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1), 20))
```

Donde '20' es la curvatura de los bordes.
 Los elementos de la lista tienen forma de rectángulo blanco con el texto correspondiente. Para hacer que los rectángulos se adopten a esa forma uso SetClip

```
    G = e.Graphics
    Dim nRegion As New Region(XRoundRectangle(New Rectangle(-1, -1, Width + 1, Height + 1), 20))

    G.SetClip(nRegion, CombineMode.Intersect)
```

No comprendo muy bien el segundo parámetro de la función SetClip, pero funciona.
El problema es que si bien funciona, el color blanco sobresale por muy poco en las esquinas.
Entonces quería saber si es posible que el Clip sólo se aplicara para la parte del código donde se crean los elementos de la lista y no la parte donde dibujo el contorno de la figura. Es posible?
Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: viste esto? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.combinemode?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Como podría usar eso para que solamente recorte los elementos de la lista y no el marco?

Comment: Probaste con los otros modos?

Comment: Si. Lo que hacen la mayoría de los otros modos es invertir todo. Recortan todo lo que este por dentro de la región. En si el modo Intersect funciona, pero quizás no pule bien los bordes y por eso se escapa un poco mas allá de donde debería

Comment: Puede ser.. esperemos a ver si alguien la tiene mas clara...